# jq reverse data structure and append to array

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I have:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Trevor",
    "fruits": ["apple", "banana"]
  }, {
    "name": "Lily",
    "fruits": ["apple", "haribo"]
  }
]
```

And I want a `jq` filter to kind of reverse the data structure, and get the names in an array:

```json
[
  {
    "fruit": "apple",
    "liked_by": ["Trevor", "Lily"]
  }, {
    "fruit": "banana",
    "liked_by": ["Trevor"]
  }, {
    "fruit": "haribo",
    "liked_by": ["Lily"]
  }
]
```

I am trying things like this:

```bash
jq '
  [
    .[]
    | .name as $name
    | .fruits[]
    | {"name": $name, "liked_by": += [.]}
  ]
' input.json
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be using `group_by` with some `map`s to bring the parts in place:

```bash
map(.fruit = .fruits[]) | group_by(.fruit)
| map({fruit: first.fruit, liked_by: map(.name)})
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/zT4DNJUAWlj)

---

Another way would be creating an index (dictionary) using nested `reduce`s, then `map`ping the result back to an array:

```bash
reduce .[] as {$name, $fruits} ({}; reduce $fruits[] as $fruit (.;
  .[$fruit] |= (.fruit = $fruit | .liked_by += [$name])
)) | map(.)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/M_zAc_Vy8zF)

---

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "fruit": "apple",
    "liked_by": [
      "Trevor",
      "Lily"
    ]
  },
  {
    "fruit": "banana",
    "liked_by": [
      "Trevor"
    ]
  },
  {
    "fruit": "haribo",
    "liked_by": [
      "Lily"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Oh wow, I see that this works, but as of yet, fail to understand why (let alone come up with a solution like this myself). I have some studying to do. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it works! Try out the following snippets producing intermediate states, which can clarify the process these approaches are going through. For the first: `map(.fruit = .fruits[])` and `map(.fruit = .fruits[]) | group_by(.fruit)`; for the second `.[]`, `.[] as {$name, $fruits} | $fruits[]`, `.[] as {$name, $fruits} | $fruits[] as $fruit | {$fruit, $name}` and `reduce .[] as {$name, $fruits} ({}; reduce $fruits[] as $fruit (.; .[$fruit] |= (.fruit = $fruit | .liked_by += [$name])))`